# SAS Proc Template: Only Outside Table Border Control

Tags: templates, formatting, sas, border

I have a custom `PROC TEMPLATE` essentally all set up except that I cannot get ONLY  the outside frame of the table to be double lines. I can get the top of the table to be double when I use:

```
STYLE TABLEHEADERCONTAINER /
    BORDERTOPSTYLE=DOUBLE
;
```

But the bottom of the table will not show a double line when I use:

```
STYLE TABLEFOOTERCONTAINER /
    BORDERTOPSTYLE=DOUBLE
;
```

Nor does the above work with `BORDERBOTTOMSTYLE`. On top of this issue, I am unable to get the left and right sides of the table to have double lines. Can anyone offer any insight into this? Below is my entire template:

```
** CREATE CUSTOM STYLE WITH ARIAL 10 PT **;
PROC TEMPLATE;
   DEFINE STYLE STYLES.STARFOX;
   PARENT=STYLES.RTF;
   STYLE USERTEXT FROM USERTEXT / FONTSIZE=3.5 FONTSTYLE=ROMAN JUST=L; /*INFO FOR THE ODS TEXT STATEMENTS*/

   STYLE FONTS /
      'TITLEFONT2' = ("<SANS-SERIF>, <MTSANS-SERIF>, ARIAL",2,BOLD)
      'TITLEFONT' = ("<SANS-SERIF>, <MTSANS-SERIF>, ARIAL",3,BOLD)
      'STRONGFONT' = ("<SANS-SERIF>, <MTSANS-SERIF>, ARIAL",2,BOLD)
      'EMPHASISFONT' = ("<SANS-SERIF>, <MTSANS-SERIF>, ARIAL",2)
      'FIXEDFONT' = ("<MONOSPACE>, COURIER",2)
      'BATCHFIXEDFONT' = ("SAS MONOSPACE, <MONOSPACE>, COURIER, MONOSPACE",2)
      'FIXEDHEADINGFONT' = ("<MONOSPACE>, COURIER, MONOSPACE",2)
      'FIXEDSTRONGFONT' = ("<MONOSPACE>, COURIER, MONOSPACE",2,BOLD)
      'FIXEDEMPHASISFONT' = ("<MONOSPACE>, COURIER, MONOSPACE",2)
      'HEADINGEMPHASISFONT' = ("<SANS-SERIF>, <MTSANS-SERIF>, ARIAL",2,BOLD )
      'HEADINGFONT' = ("<SANS-SERIF>, <MTSANS-SERIF>, ARIAL",2,BOLD)
      'DOCFONT' = ("<SANS-SERIF>, <MTSANS-SERIF>, ARIAL",2);
   ;

   STYLE TABLEHEADERCONTAINER /
   BORDERTOPSTYLE=DOUBLE
   ;

   STYLE TABLEFOOTERCONTAINER /
   BORDERTOPSTYLE=DOUBLE
   ;

   STYLE DATA / 
   FONT_FACE = "ARIAL"
   FONT_SIZE = 10PT
   JUST=CENTER
   VJUST=C
   ;

   STYLE TABLE /
   CELLSPACING = 0.7
   CELLPADDING = 1.4
   FONT_SIZE = 10
   JUST=CENTER
   VJUST=C
   BORDERWIDTH=1
   FRAME=BOX
   ;

   STYLE HEADER /
   FONT_FACE = "ARIAL"
   FONT_SIZE = 10PT
   FONT_WEIGHT = BOLD
   JUST=CENTER
   VJUST=C
   ;

   STYLE ROWHEADER /
   FONT_FACE = "ARIAL"
   FONT_SIZE = 10
   JUST=CENTER
   VJUST=C
   ;

   STYLE FOOTER / 
   FONT_FACE = "ARIAL"
   FONT_SIZE=10
   JUST=CENTER VJUST=C
   ;

   REPLACE COLOR_LIST /
   "BG" = WHITE
   "FG" = BLACK
   "BGH" = WHITE
   "LINK" = BLUE;

   STYLE BODY FROM DOCUMENT /
      TOPMARGIN=.8IN
      BOTTOMMARGIN=.8IN
      RIGHTMARGIN=.9IN;
   END;
RUN;
```

Below is how the output table appears:

[image]

And I would like it to appear as:

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't you need to switch to `BORDERBOTTOMSTYLE` in the footer container style?

Comment: Tried that as well and it doesn't work. A template online had `BORDERTOPSTYLE` which is why I used it.

Comment: What version of SAS do you run?  Also, are you familiar with CSS (and HTML)?

Comment: I'm running version 9.3 and not familiar with either.

Comment: Hmm, too bad.  9.4 has the ability to use a CSS style that's not defined in SAS's limited language - which would make this pretty easy.  I think I know the problem here (I think your table doesn't generate a footer, so tablefootercontainer is never called), but I don't have a solution - unless Reeza or Tom or someone knows the answer here, I would pop over to [communities.sas.com](http://communities.sas.com/) and see if Cynthia can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the info, @Joe. I plan on upgrading SAS soon just haven't come around to it!